# How to convert string representation of dictionary in Pandas DataFrame to a new columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a string representation of dictionary in Pandas DataFrame Column like  this:

```
>>> df['the_column']
    
0 "{'a': 1., 'b': 2., 'c':3.}"
1 "{'a': 4., 'b': 5., 'c':6.}"
2 "{'a': 7., 'b': 8., 'c': 9.}"
3 "{'a': 10., 'b': 11., 'c':12.}"
    ...
```

I want to append each keys to columns in the existing DataFrame, how is it possible?

I have tried something like this:

```
list_of_new_col = [json.loads(c) for c in df['the_column']]
# resulting list of dictionary
# convert it to pandas DataFrame
# and then concat with the existing DataFrame
```

but I got
`TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'float'`

Any idea on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try with `ast`

```
import ast
df['the_column']=df['the_column'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer I found this works as well

```
pd.concat([df, df.the_column.apply(json.loads).apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```